Изменится ли предлог, если убрать из словосочетания родовое слово?
Помогите, разобраться, пожалуйста. Была вот станция "Мир", но какие предлоги верно употреблять с ней, когда нет родового слова "станция"?
Живём на/в "Мире".
Держит путь из/с "Мира".
ДОПОЛНЕНО (28.12.2024)
"Грамота.ру" наконец ответила (см. ответ на вопрос № 320693):

В этом случае корректно: живем на «Мире», держит путь с «Мира».


• Название "Мир" носит не только пилотируемая научно-исследовательская орбитальная станция, но и кимберлитовая трубка (карьер, месторождение), и глубоководный аппарат (комплекс, батискаф).
• Изменится ли предлог, если убрать из словосочетания родовое слово?
Нет, не изменится.
В каждом конкретном случае выбор предлога делается так, как будто родовое слово присутствует (исходим из варианта, что мы знаем, о чём говорим):
на станции "Мир" — живём на "Мире";
со станции "Мир" — держим путь с "Мира".
• Примеры
Валерий Поляков стал абсолютным мировым рекордсменом, он пробыл на «Мире» непрерывно 438 суток, а по суммарному времени за два полета набрал 679 суток. За время полета на «Мире» побывало 105 человек (Б. Е. Черток. Ракеты и люди).
Мы спускались на «Мире» на дно Атлантического океана к затонувшему «Титанику» (И. Смазневич, А. М. Сагалевич. Вглубь смотрящий).
